# Need to type a right triangle symbol but unicode input problem

Tags: symbols

I need to type a right triangle symbol, whose unicode is 
`U+22BF` or `U+25FF`, see

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/25ff/index.htm

What I get in the template I used is

```
\RequirePackage[T1]{fontenc}            
\RequirePackage[utf8]{inputenc}     
\RequirePackage{lmodern}
```

I don't want to change to `utf8x`.

The engine I use is `pdflatex`.

I can't figure out how to make it work. Is there a way to type the unicode code
to obtain the unicode symbol in output?

Comment: You need a font that has this character, and some files to use it with (pdf)latex. I don't think Latin Modern has.

Comment: Do you need the symbol in math and scalable in superscripts/subscripts?

Answer (score 5):

Picture mode to the rescue:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pict2e}

\DeclareRobustCommand{\lowerrighttriangle}{%
  \begingroup
  \setlength{\unitlength}{1ex}%
  \begin{picture}(1,1)
  \polyline(1,0)(0,0)(1,1)(1,0)(.5,0)
  \end{picture}%
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

x \lowerrighttriangle{} y

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Why is there the `(.5,0)` at the end of the polyline? Why not use `\polygon(1,0)(0,0)(1,1)`?